# Updating with random data fails for php pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to update my table with a randomly generated data field with this script

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10 ; $i++){
    $date = rand(1,30).'/'.rand(1,12).'/'.'15';
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=qp', 'root', '123456');
    $sth2 = $dbh->prepare("update r_data set the_date = '$date' where transaction_type = 'send'");
    echo $date.'<br/>';
    $sth2->execute();
}
```

but the field  is only updated with only one random string i.e `18/5/15` but the variable `$date` has generated random dates as i want.

Why is the date field not being updated with random data?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are updating the *same row(s)* each time. Once the loop is done, you'll only see the last 'random' value in the database, as all preceding values will have been replaced.

You'll have to qualify the rows your are updating to be different each iteration of your loop if you want to see different dates for different rows.

Alternatively, have MySQL insert random dates for you:

```
update r_data set 
the_date = DATE '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 365) DAY
where transaction_type = 'send'
```

This'll insert a different random date value for each selected row; no loop required.